# Referencing a blank cell - should act like a blank cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that referencing a blank cell on another tab.  I use the iif(isblank(thatcell),"",thatcell).  This works fine, until I use that cell to calculate.  When I include that cell to calculate standard deviation (or even counta(), it treats the blank cell as zero.  I wonder if there is another way around it.  It'll be best if excel can create a function blankcell() in place of "".  Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Blanks are zeros for any formula unless it specifically excludes blanks. Your best bet would be to use a user-defined function within VBA for your project. Something like:

```
Sub SumNonBlanks()
 For each c in range("A:A")
  If c.value <> "" then
  'Enter them into an array
  End if
 Next
'Do stuff to array
End Sub
```

---

One workaround is to exclude zeroes in your formula, something similar to `=SUM(if(A1:A10 <> 0,A1:A10))` entered as an array formula.

Array formulas are entered by typing it out and then pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>.

*The disputed part*: But if you need to include zeros you'd need to get more complex like <s>`=SUM(IF(Not(Isblank(...`</s> `=sumif(not(isblank(...` as an array formula.

Comment: The problem isn't that blanks are treated as zero by formulae (they're not always), it's that a null text string, created by "", is not blank. Excluding zeroes would work, unless other zeroes need to be included, but the =SUM(IF(Not(Isblank(... solution would not work, because the cell is not blank.

Comment: @toryan You're a bit mistaken. Run some VBA, a simple `cells(1,1)=""` and perform an `=isblank(a1)` - you'll see "true"

Comment: That's odd. If you enter ="" into cell A1, then =ISBLANK(A1) into A2, it returns FALSE indicating that A1 is not blank. Maybe behaviour is different when you enter a null text string using VBA vs entering it directly into the cell. In any case, if you run ISBLANK on a cell containing a formula that returns "" (as the questioner is doing), you definitely get a value of FALSE.

Comment: @toryan the double quote " is a character. VBA is machine-level. Formulae aren't. With, A1=1, B1=if(a1=1,"") and c1=isblank(b1)=FALSE. It's the act of setting a cell to the null string with the `if`. My formula does not define it that way.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative workaround, which doesn't involve writing custom functions, would be to use the `AGGREGATE` function to calculate the standard deviation. The advantage of this function is that, unlike `SUM` or `STDEV`, it can ignore errors.

In order for this to work, you need to make your first cell return an error instead of a null text string. In your first cell, enter

```
=IF(ISBLANK(ThatCell),NA(),H23)
```

The `NA` function simply returns an #N/A error.

Then, instead of using `STDEV` to calculate the standard deviation, use

```
=AGGREGATE(7,6,Range)
```

The first option in the `AGGREGATE` function, in this case `7` tells it to perform a STDEV.S calculation (to use STDEV.P, use `8`). The second option, in this case `6`, tells the function to ignore errors. Since you told `IF` to return an #N/A error in place of a blank cell, that cell will be ignored.

[AGGREGATE function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/aggregate-function-HA010338704.aspx)

[NA function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/mac-excel-help/na-function-HA102927881.aspx?CTT=1)

Comment: `isblank` returns 0 or 1, FALSE or TRUE, nothing else, including null strings. `if` returns anything you put in it.

Comment: @Raystafarian yep, typo, now fixed :)

Comment: Right, my point was to bypass the `if` all-together. `if` will return non-blanks. Do the formula to the data bypassing the return of the `if`. Considering the OP asks about `stdev` and `counta` I read it as *"and others"* providing a general solution, rather than a specific one, like yours. Note I'm not suggesting that mine is any more valid than yours.